# How can I extract html links from rtf text copied to the mac system clipboard?

Tags: macos, clipboard, rtf

After copying text with hyperlinks in an email message, I'd like to be able to extract the links for further processing (rather than the titles of the links.)  Is there a way to get the urls for further processing?

Answer (score 2):

`pbpaste -Prefer rtf` did not suffice because it pastes the plain rendered text.
I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548429/411282) which shows how to extract the raw `rtf` code.  Then from that I was able to grep for the links.

```
osascript -e 'the clipboard as "RTF "' | \
  perl -ne 'print chr foreach unpack("C*",pack("H*",substr($_,11,-3)))' | \
  grep -o 'http[^"]*'
```

Note, this can be used to open a bunch of emailed links by adding one more step:

```
... | xargs open
```